# Cannot find IfcProduct.Transform() method in Ifc4 namespace ! (Xbim.Essentials)

Tags: matrix, transform, ifc, xbim

I am using IfcProduct.Transform() method to obtain the transformation matrix (XbimMatrix3D instance) and using that to do conversions between relative and absolute placements.

But I am not able to find those functions in Ifc4 namespace! I am not able to find anything else that is meant to substitute these functions. This issue has been highlighted here too: https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/issues/103, but there is no response. Please help!

Comment: I can build the matrix manually but I want to learn the intended use in the Ifc4 namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this all got refactored in the IFC4 updates so that transforms on IfcObjectPlacements are handled in Xbim.Geometry.Engine against interfaces in `Xbim.Ifc4.Interfaces`

I'd take a look at https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/blob/08920df29f909dde0c4f65c63d80ae0b5540025f/Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop/XbimGeometryEngine.cs#L442